# How to list all packages provided by conda?

Tags: conda

Is there a list or a command that would show all packages available for installation for anaconda?

Namely, I would like to know if conda has a package for tensorflow v1.5 compiled for CUDA 8.0 and I have some expectations about how it would be called, but I can not tell for sure if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
conda search *tensorflow*
```

will search your default conda channels for any packages with `tensorflow` in their name. (The wildcard asterisks are required with conda 4.x up.)

```
conda search --help
```

will show you help on the options for this command. In particular you might find further versions of this package if you include the `conda-forge` channel, which might not be configured as one of your defaults in your `.condarc` file.